# How to redirect to shop after logged in user in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, login, redirect

```
 public function execute()
{
    if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('/shop/');  //Here  i changed but not working 
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
            try {
                $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
                $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                $this->session->regenerateId();
                if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
                    $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
                    $metadata->setPath('');
                    $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
                }
                $redirectUrl = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
                if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectUrl) {
                    $this->accountRedirect->clearRedirectCookie();
                    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                    // URL is checked to be internal in $this->_redirect->success()
                    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($redirectUrl));
                    return $resultRedirect;
                }
            } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                $value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                $message = __(
                    'This account is not confirmed. <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.',
                    $value
                );
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (UserLockedException $e) {
                $message = __(
                    'You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.'
                );
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                $message = __('You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.');
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                // PA DSS violation: throwing or logging an exception here can disclose customer password
                $this->messageManager->addError(
                    __('An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance.')
                );
            }
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('A login and a password are required.'));
        }
    }

    return $this->accountRedirect->getRedirect();
}
```

}

> Customer/controller/account/loginpost.php

```
if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */

$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

$resultRedirect->setPath('/shop/'); **//Here I changed, but not working**
```

How I can solve this ???

any help

Comment: You doing wrong... please check the condition. You have tried to redirect to shop page when you have already logged IN or Your form key is already   invalid

Comment: where the path i can change

Answer (score 0):

At mageto2, `Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect:getRedirect()` is reposirbale for redirection after login.

***from this method, Magento set prepare redirection URL, So, if you want change Magento default to redirect logic, then you have to work at this method.***

In my option, best to use **around** `(aroundGetRedirect())` plugin over `getRedirect()`

**Plugin Class:**

```
<?php
namespace Devamitbera\CustomerRedirection\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;


class Redirect
{

    private $url;

    private $resultFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        UrlInterface $url, 
        ResultFactory $resultFactory)
    {

        $this->url = $url;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function aroundGetRedirect ($subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {

        $allowActions = ['loginpost','createpost'];
        // Customer  redirection when   createpost and loginpost hit 
        if(in_array(strtolower($this->request->getActionName()),$allowActions)){
                    $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('shop));
            return $result;
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Create **di.ml** at `app/code/Devamitbera/CustomerRedirection/etc/`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect">
        <plugin name="NewAcctRedirectPlug" type="Devamitbera\CustomerRedirection\Plugin\Redirect" disabled="false" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: where i can  in   di.xml   file